# Submit jobs to Apache-Spark while being behind a firewall

Tags: python, apache-spark

Usecase:
I'm behind a firewall, and I have a remote spark cluster I can access to, however those machines cannot connect directly to me.

As Spark [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/cluster-overview.html) states it is necessary for the worker to be able to reach the driver program:

> Because the driver schedules tasks on the cluster, it should be run
>   close to the worker nodes, preferably on the same local area network.
>   If you’d like to send requests to the cluster remotely, it’s better to
>   open an RPC to the driver and have it submit operations from nearby
>   than to run a driver far away from the worker nodes.

The suggested solution is to have a server process running on the cluster listening to RPC and let it execute itself the spark driver program locally.

Does such a program already exists? Such a process should manage 1+ RPC, returning exceptions and handling logs.

Also in that case, is my local program or the spark driver who has to create the SparkContext?

Note:
I have a standalone cluster

**Solution1**:

A simple way would be to use cluster mode (similar to `--deploy-mode cluster`) for the standalone cluster, however the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) says:

> Currently, standalone mode does not support cluster mode for Python
>   applications.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few options:

- Connect to the cluster node using `ssh`, start `screen`, submit Spark application, go back to check the results.
- Deploy middleware like Job Server, Livy or Mist on your cluster, and use it for submissions.
- Deploy notebook (Zeppelin, Toree) on your cluster and submit applications from the notebook.
- Set fixed `spark.driver.port` and `ssh` forward all connections through one of the cluster nodes, using its IP as `spark.driver.bindAddress`.